# How can we pass a variable( string) to an xpath contains function?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I need to find an element that contains a particular text. How can I do that without hardcoding the text. How can I make the text a variable and pass it to the `xpath` function?

```
public static void selectEvent(String eventName) { 

WebElement eventLink = Browser.instance.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]/a[1][contains(text(), 'Birthday Party')]")); 
eventLink.click(); 
}
```

Here instead of using the text *Birthday Party* I need to use the parameter *eventName* that has been passed to the method.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! It would be of great help (and motivation) to the community if you showed effort in your question. What have you already tried yourself? What problems did you ran into? SO is the wrong place to simply ask for a solution.

Comment: public static void selectEvent(String eventName) 
 {
  WebElement eventLink = Browser.instance.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]/a[1][contains(text(), 'Birthday Party')]"));
  
  eventLink.click();
 } Here instead of using the text 'Birthday Party' I need to use the parameter eventName that has been passed to the method..

Comment: Thank you for the code, but please edit your question so it reflects this with proper formatting. That way others can see everything in one go and can provide you with pointers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using java then declare a method which returns particular element,

```
public WebElement getElementByXpathContainsText(String xpath)
    {
    return webDriver.findElement(By.ByXPath(xpath));
    }
```

Just call getElementByXpathContainsText() by passing any xpath as parameter.

for your code try following way,

```
public static void selectEvent(String eventName) { 
WebElement eventLink = Browser.instance.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]/a[1][contains(text(), '"+eventName+"')]")); eventLink.click(); 
}
```

Comment: When I try to pass eventName = "ABC 1 internal" it gives me a error " 'value' must be a string. Note that I am using this xpath in python. I believe this should be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your class, and call the same:

```
public WebElement findElementUsingText(String searchText)
{
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'"+searchText+"')]"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

' "+variable+" '
This way you can input your variable with
XPath=@"........."
Type

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).